# How to combine multiple json arrays in groovy

Tags: groovy

In jenkins I need to an api call multiple times. Every iteration, i will need to get a part of the api response which is an array of json and put it into a global array variable so that this will store all the data after calling the api multiple times. I tried array.plus every iteration but it doesn't seem to work. It returns an empty array. So basically how can I combine multiple array of JSON objects in groovy?

```
globalDataArray = []

idsList.each { id ->
    sh """
        curl --location --request GET "http://some-api.com" > api-response.json
    """
    def responseJson = readJSON file: 'api-response.json'
    globalDataArray.plus(responseJson.data)
}
```

sample api response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Araceli Carver"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Chasity Miranda"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Lydia May"
        }
    ],
}
```

Expected value of globalDataArray after the iteration should be

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Araceli Carver"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Chasity Miranda"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Lydia May"
    },
    ... //whatever values the api returns during each iteration
]
```

Comment: Are you actually using curly braces for your map? You should use `['name':...`, but maybe that's just a typo for the example? And yes, when the lists of maps are declared correctly, `arr1.plus(arr2)` works as you expect.

Comment: its just an example. The actual values will be the response from the api which is still an array of json objects similar to the example i have in the question.

Comment: Then your problem cannot be reproduced. What is your actual data type for `arr1` and `arr2`? If they are lists as your question suggests, then there's no reason for it to fail.

Comment: Also, your example seems to be not compilable, I get this error:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
HelloWorld.groovy: 2: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 2, column 10.
      'name': 'john doe',
            ^

1 error

Comment: Edited my question to reflect the actual code im using.

Answer (score 0):

`plus` does NOT change the original array.

Your code should look like:

```
def globalDataArray = idsList.collectMany{ id ->
    sh """
        curl --location --request GET "http://some-api.com" > api-response.json
    """
    def responseJson = readJSON file: 'api-response.json'
    responseJson.data
}
```